# Permission Denied in sound cloud player

Tags: html, soundcloud

Here is my code:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/101728459&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
```

But when I play the sound, the track is played but I am unable to stop the song. When I check the console, it appears.

> Exception: Error: Permission denied to access property "toString"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rj5vy5eu/ - It works fine in a fiddle. The cause of your problem is outside this code. Could you provide some more context?

Comment: I have integrated in just plain view. The app is developed in Laravel and there is nothing more in the view. Why am I having problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which browser are using? and what what is the version of browser?
try adding `?html5=1` to your embed URL.

Comment: I am using Firefox v40.0. It worked in chrome. Can you say why am I having problem in forefox?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like a problem with the embedded player, but most likely a local issue. Try using another browser or reset the cookies/cache and try again.

Here are the parameters the embedded SoundCloud Player can use:

> color=(hex code without #, like 33ff00) for play button and other
>   controls
>
> theme_color=(hex code without #, like 33ff00) for player background
>   etc.
>
> auto_play=true/false
>
> show_artwork=true/false
>
> show_playcount=true/false
>
> show_bpm=true/false
>
> show_comments=true/false
>
> text_buy_track = string (e.g. ‘Tweet’ and it points to your ‘buy’
>   link)
>
> text_buy_set = string (e.g. ‘Tweet’ and it points to your ‘buy’ link)
>
> text_download_track = string (e.g. ‘Get it’ and it points to your
>   ‘download’ link)
>
> buying = true/false (show hide buy buttons)
>
> sharing = true/false (show hide share buttons)
>
> download = true/false (show hide download buttons)
>
> show_bpm = true/false (show hide bpm display in player)
>
> show_playcount = true/false (show hide number of track plays)
>
> start_track = (a number from 0 to the playlist length) preselects a
>   track in a playlist
>
> default_width = (a number e.g. 400) overrides the player’s autoscale,
>   useful when embedding in other flash movies
>
> default_height = (a number e.g. 500) overrides the player’s autoscale,
>   useful when embedding in other flash movies
>
> font = (a string e.g. Arial) overrides the default font with system
>   font
>
> enable_api = true/false (enable JS api callbacks, please refer to
>   http://wiki.github.com/soundcloud/Widget-JS-API/ for docs)
>
> single_active = true/false (if set to false the multiple players on
>   the page won’t toggle each other off when playing)
>
> show_user = true/false (show or hide the uploader name, useful e.g. in
>   tiny players to save space)

If clearing cache/cookies fails to work then try playing with some of the parameters above.

Comment: Nice; this doesn't directly relate to the question, but it's a really good resource you got here!